# Transient HTTP errors when performing load_table_from_file() call from the Python BigQuery client library

Tags: google-bigquery

Throughout the past few days I have been getting transient HTTP Errors from the Google BigQuery API when loading data via the load_table_from_file() method in the BigQuery client library. Sometimes it will work, sometimes not, any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
ReadTimeout(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)",)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a ticket in the BQ issue tracker and received response that this is due to an ongoing incident with load jobs.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161718186